# Primeng datatable responsiveness issue

Tags: angular, responsive, primeng

i am currently learning how to use primeng datatable in our project, i have an issue about the responsiveness of this table. The table is responsive if the web page is in its normal size or when we decrease its size while having separators such as space, hyphen between words. But, we observe that if we have a long text in one of its columns, it will not be responsive anymore while we decrease the size of the web page.

The web page with a normal size :
[web page with normal size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7PWO.png)

The web page when i decrease its size :

[web page with decrease in size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j09H8.png)

My html code is :

```html
<p-dataTable [value]="memberList" [responsive]="true" [stacked]="stacked" >

    <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" >

    </p-column>

</p-dataTable>
```

My typeScript code is :

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from "@angular/common/http";
import {AccordionModule} from "primeng/primeng";
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/api' ;
import {DataTableModule} from "primeng/datatable";


export interface Member
{
    userName;
    email;
    jobTitle;
    status;
    phoneNumber;
    joinDate;
}



@Component({
    selector: 'app-member-liste',
    templateUrl: './member-liste.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./member-liste.component.css']
})
export class MemberListeComponent implements OnInit {

    memberList: string[] ;
    members: Member[] ;
    cols: any[] ;

    displayedColumns = ['userName', 'email' , 'status', 'phoneNumber', 'joinDate'];

    constructor( private httpService: HttpClient) {

    }



    ngOnInit() {

        this.httpService.get('./assets/membresTable.json').subscribe(
            data => {
                this.memberList = data as string [];
            },
            (err: HttpErrorResponse ) => {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        );

        this.cols = [
            {field: 'userName', header: 'UserName'},
            {field: 'email', header: 'Email'},
            {field: 'jobTitle', header: 'JobTitle'},
            {field: 'status', header: 'Status'},
            {field: 'phoneNumber', header: 'PhoneNumber'},
            {field: 'joinDate', header: 'JoinDate'}
        ] ;

    }




}
```

I will be very grateful if you can help me resolving this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from "@angular/common/http";
import {AccordionModule} from "primeng/primeng";
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/api' ;
import {DataTableModule} from "primeng/datatable";


export interface Member
{
    userName;
    email;
    jobTitle;
    status;
    phoneNumber;
    joinDate;
}



@Component({
    selector: 'app-member-liste',
    templateUrl: './member-liste.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./member-liste.component.css']
})
export class MemberListeComponent implements OnInit {

    memberList: string[] ;
    members: Member[] ;
    cols: any[] ;

    displayedColumns = ['userName', 'email' , 'status', 'phoneNumber', 'joinDate'];

    constructor( private httpService: HttpClient) {

    }



    ngOnInit() {

        this.httpService.get('./assets/membresTable.json').subscribe(
            data => {
                this.memberList = data as string [];
            },
            (err: HttpErrorResponse ) => {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        );

        this.cols = [
            {field: 'userName', header: 'UserName'},
            {field: 'email', header: 'Email'},
            {field: 'jobTitle', header: 'JobTitle'},
            {field: 'status', header: 'Status'},
            {field: 'phoneNumber', header: 'PhoneNumber'},
            {field: 'joinDate', header: 'JoinDate'}
        ] ;

    }




}
```

i have resolved the issue by adding "word-break : break-all" to the file.css of the component.

i have read the following document : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break.